# rChart lineChart with Multiple Series

Tags: r, rcharts

I'm sure this is an easy question but I cannot seem to find the answer.  Just starting out with R and rCharts and I'm trying to create a line chart with week on the horizontal axis and two price variables as the series.  The data is just a standard data frame with columns Week, Price1, and Price2.  I've tried:

```
n1 <- nPlot(Price1 + Price2 ~ Week, data=quotes, type = "lineChart")
```

but that does not plot any of the series.  If I take out Price 1 or Price 2 and the "+" it works fine, but is there a way to plot both simultaneously?  I know about the group= option, but I'd rather not have to restructure the data to get that to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible.  Currently, most of the rCharts libraries work with long data, so `reshape2::melt` is your friend.  Based on the question, it sounds like you are aware of how to accomplish this, but I am happy to help if you need.